# I need to use a function of one class from another class in kivy python

Tags: python, kivy

I have a problem when creating and using data table in kivy, this is my code structure in brief.

There are two buttons in the screen one inside the `Example` class and one outside the `Example` class
and the two buttons should execute the same function.

I need to call the method `update_row_data` to update the data table rows from `Example()` class when click any one of the two buttons.

```py
from kivy.metrics import dp

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string("""

<All>:
    Test:
    Example:

""")

class All(Screen):
    pass


class Test(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.test()
    

    def test(self):
        self.add_widget(MDRaisedButton(
                text="Change 2 row",
                pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5},
                on_press = Example().update_row_data,
                y=24,
            ))

class Example(BoxLayout):
    data_tables = None

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.build_()


    def build_(self):
        self.layout = MDFloatLayout()
        self.layout.add_widget(
            MDRaisedButton(
                text="Change 2 row",
                pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5},
                on_release=self.update_row_data,
                y=24,
            )
        )
        self.data_tables = MDDataTable(
            pos_hint={"center_y": 0.5, "center_x": 0.5},
            size_hint=(0.9, 0.6),
            use_pagination=False,
            column_data=[
                ("No.", dp(30)),
                ("Column 1", dp(40)),
                ("Column 2", dp(40)),
                ("Column 3", dp(40)),
            ],
            row_data=[(f"{i + 1}", "1", "2", "3") for i in range(3)],
        )
        self.layout.add_widget(self.data_tables)
        self.add_widget(self.layout)


    def update_row_data(self, instance_button):
        self.data_tables.row_data = [('1','1','1','1')]
        print(self.data_tables.row_data)





class App(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return All()



App().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are creating a new instance of class `Example` and invoke it's method `update_row_data` each time you press the button. That way though it indeed does the job, you can't see it happening because it is not in your current GUI model.

The fix is to acess exactly that `Example` class you have added to your `root`. One of the many ways to do that is keeping a reference of that class (say, by `id`) and access that properly. Below is the corresponding implementation of this idea,

First create a reference in `kvlang`,

```py
<All>:
    Test:
    Example:
        id: example
```

Now in method `test` of class `Test`,

```py
    def test(self):
        self.add_widget(MDRaisedButton(
                text="Change 2 rows",
                pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5},
                on_press = self.update_row,
                y=24,
            ))
        
    def update_row(self, btn):
        # Access that class already added to your `root`.
        example_cls = self.parent.ids.example
        # Now make the call.
        example_cls.update_row_data(btn)
```

---

### Note:

You have added both of your classes to a `Screen` (without specifying relative `size` or `pos`, you can check it yourself by adding canvas). Thus they will sit on top of other and may be troublesome if there are different types of widgets. You better chose `ScreenManager` instead.